# Download pdf file from angular4+ webserver

Tags: angular, angular-cli

On the webpage we are trying to add a button that downloads the manual for the webpage. Frontend is done with angular4+ and apiis java spring.

Is there a way to add the manual file to webserver with the frontend so that when user wants the manual there is no need to contact the API?

Everything I have been able to find only is about how to download file from API. Is it possible to download file from the webserver using angular or can file downloads only be done from the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this architecture, whenever a browser navigates to your site, the the webserver will provide all of the files requested (all css, js, html files, etc.).  They are static files.  You don't necessarily need to contact the api, but you could just point to a static file, by the use of anchor tags:

```
<a href='/static/help.pdf' target="_blank">Download</a>
```

Or you can always convert your help into a html page, and incorporate it into your web application.

Comment: Does this mean, that every time the page is opened, the pdf file would be downloaded. And when user klicks the button the download window will open ? Or will the pdf be dowloaded only if the button is clicked?

Comment: No - it will download to disk upon clicking the link.  What you are asking, to fetch on page load, and to store in the browser's addressable memory space, until you want to view it is not possible.  What is your use case? Do you just want to display it in the browser? If so, then you could use pdf.js: https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

Comment: Oh good. then it does what is needed. I was just afraid that it just might download the pdf everytime the page is opened. Thank you.